# UDP send buffer error in netstat

Tags: linux, ethernet, udp, buffer, interface

I we are running voice application which stream UDP (RTP) packets for voice, I am investigation some strange issue where my `ifconfig ens4 | grep error` counter going up specifically `overrun`

If you see UDP send buffer error that counter is getting increase periodically, does that means my TX buffer is getting full?

```
[root@voice-01 ~]# netstat -suna
...
Udp:
    564240050621 packets received
    600156354 packets to unknown port received.
    3095742 packet receive errors
    621737694201 packets sent
    0 receive buffer errors
    1475161 send buffer errors
    InCsumErrors: 913878
...
```

Interface overrun counter

```
[root@voice-01 ~]# ifconfig ens4 | grep -i error
        RX errors 15147252  dropped 0  overruns 15147252  frame 0
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

overrun directly involve with high speed RX data where kernel can't process hard enough, i have increase udp buffer size also but still time to time overrun counter getting increased.

sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=26214400
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_default=26214400
sysctl -w net.core_wrmem_default=26214400
sysctl -w net.core_wmem_default=26214400

ethtool stats

```
[root@voice-01 ~]# ethtool -S ens4 | grep rx_dis
     [0]: rx_discards: 1764406
     [1]: rx_discards: 1655431
     [2]: rx_discards: 1418942
     [3]: rx_discards: 1880233
     [4]: rx_discards: 1950109
     [5]: rx_discards: 2227701
     [6]: rx_discards: 1095657
     [7]: rx_discards: 3154773
     rx_discards: 15147252
```

I have exact similar hardware voice-02 box which is also handling same amount of traffic but it has almost `zero` error

I have NIC is `Broadcom Limited NetXtreme II BCM57810 10 Gigabit Ethernet`

what other option i should try or understand what is wrong?